# How can I deny a bind lookup on a single IP address?

Tags: ip, bind, address

I am running a BIND installation as a simple RBL server.  The problem I am running in to is that if I have listed a block of IP addresses like:

*.0.0.10.rbl.mydomain.net.        IN      A       127.0.0.1

*.0.0.10.rbl.mydomain.net.        IN      TXT     "Excessive Spam"

This meets all the requirements so that mail servers will reject the entire class C block.

The problem comes in if I need to delist one IP address in the middle of the block, such as 10.0.0.100 for this example.

Is there a way I can do this without having to write 252 discrete host listings and skipping this one address?  I have tried adding a legitimate IP as the rDNS address but mail servers still count that as listed.

Much appreciation for your help and advice.

Comment: You really need to be using a database, LDAP directory, or something else for this.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [$GENERATE](https://www.isc.org/files/arm96.html#id2573543) option to create the entries before and after the IP in question.

You're still creating all the entries, but at least it automated vs creating the all by hand.